# CVPixelBuffer to RGBA Buffer in iOS/Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image, buffer, arkit

I am working with ARKit and I get the ARFrame - capturedImage is of CVPixelBuffer - Currently I convert this into a CVPixelBuffer->CIImage->UIImage-> JPEG

I want to know how to get the raw buffer from CVPixelBuffer - I know that ARFrame is of YUV format and I want the image buffer in RGBA format to set as a texture in my graphics application.

I feel that CVPixelBuffer->CIImage->UImage-> JPEG is too many conversion and again decoding from JPEG->Buffer at my application is too much wasteful processing.

So the question is how do I get RGBA image buffer from CVPixelBuffer. I am using Swift

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is the fastest way. You may consider using vImage of Accelerate framework.  From there, you are given some advantages.

Comment: So there is no way to get any RGBA buffer from CVPixelBuffer? I dont know much about vImage - I will check it out and see if I can make use of it.